# App update in Google Play - November 1st 2021

Tags: android, google-play

According to https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk
app updates will need to be targeted at API level 30 or later, but I already uploaded an app update to be published on november 6th and it's approved so, would I have to load a new one for this date?  I tried to talk with someone from Google but they're taking a lot of time to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you do not need to create a new update for this date, this means that if you want to update your app you need to target API 30.